# Configurable Table Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am a beginner in lwc and I have this error :Col is not defined

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <apiVersion>54.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage,lightning__AppPage,lightning__HomePage">           
            <property name="colm" type="String" />
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

-------------------JS-----------------------

```js
 @api colm;
 get col(){
    return JSON.parse(colm);
 }
```

-------HTML-----------------------

```html
<template>
    <lightning-datatable
        key-field="Id"
        data={data}
        columns={col}
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

To access a property in a class, you need to use `this`.

```
return JSON.parse(this.colm);
```

By the way, it's not really advantageous to call a property `colm` instead of `column` or even `columns`. The computer doesn't care about what you label the variable, but you should. Plain spellings of variables, methods, and so on, make the code easier for you and others that have to maintain this code (including future you, who may forget what `colm` means).

Comment: Thanks but i have the same problem with : JSON.parse(this.colm)

Comment: @Salem Make sure that you're paying attention to case, as well. `Col` is not the same as `col`. This isn't clear in your question, but I'd have to guess that's probably the case here.